# Keep list's elements' names after applying a function to the list

Tags: r, list, apply, names

`list1` contains several square matrices, each of those is named this way

```
$name1
           [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
 [1,] 0.1997578 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 [2,] 0.0000000 0.2025 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
```

I applied `eigen.analysis` to `list1` and then the element names disappeared in the result (`list2`). So I have to rename all the elements in `list2` using `list1`'s names under the assumptions that the element orders don't change. How do I fix my code so that I can skip the name reassigning step? Thank you!

```
list2<- lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i){
  eigen.analysis(list1[[i]])
})
names(list2) <- names(list1)
```

This is how `list2` looks like before the `names()` command

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$lambda1
[1] 0.2025
```

I expect my result to be

```
$name1
$name1$lambda1
[1] 0.2025
```

`lapply(seq_along())` and `lapply(names())` all made the names disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using lapply to apply the function to indexes from `seq_along` you should apply your function directly to `list1`:

```
list2<- lapply(list1, function(x){
  eigen.analysis(x)
})
```

`list2` should be named if you use `lapply()` this way